# Finding top point in two gaussians

Tags: matlab, graph, gaussian

So i have this graph with these two gaussians created in matlab

[image]

This Graph have been created using the following bit of matlab code

```
TimeTakenWDriver = textread('TimeTakenWDriver.txt');
TimeTakenWODriver = textread('TimeTakenWODriver.txt');
fig1 = figure;

h1 = histfit(TimeTakenWDriver);
std1 = std(TimeTakenWDriver);
std2 = std(TimeTakenWODriver);
mean1 = mean(TimeTakenWDriver)
mean2 = mean(TimeTakenWODriver)
delete(h1(1));
set(h1(2),'color','b');
hold on;
h2 = histfit(TimeTakenWODriver);
delete(h2(1));
set(h2(2),'color','r');
```

Now i want to find the two y coordinates that corresponds to the two means "the two top-points" ive searched around but cant get any of the solutions i find to work because of the way i create my graphs. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure whether it is a regular plot, but otherwise you can just find the maximum by using the cursor (with your mouse). If this does not work I would try something like `max(h2(2))`

Comment: I can use the datacursor to try and locate the specific point but i gotta have a really steady hand then, the max(h2(2)) gives 178.something in this case so it seems to find the highest value on my X-axis

Comment: Not sure what you mean by steady hand, but after you click on a point near the top you can use your arrow keys to figure out which one is the optimum. For a programmatical solution you will want to dig deeper into the design of h2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try getting the data directly from the plot:

```
C = get(get(gca, 'Children'), 'YData');
```

and then find the peak value using `max`:

```
max(C(:))
```

Note that if you have two or more plots on the same axes (as in your example), `C` would be a cell array, so you need to access each cell separately to get the peaks:

```
cellfun(@(x)max(x(:)), C)
```

Comment: Is it possible to find the coordinates where these two gaussians intersect? Or the y-coordinate of one gaussian given its x value? I am plotting the gaussians using `histfit`

Comment: @user2550888 Sure, that's pretty easy. The y-coordinates (`YData`) are obtained in array `C`. Do the same for the the x-coordinates (`XData`) and store them in another array. Now, for a specific coordinate in one axis, you would be able to find the matching coordinate in another axis...